# How to solve a number theory kind of modeling problem?

Tags: combinatorics

Here is the problem:

> A brewery has $20$ people and each person can select $2$ beers to take
> home. The brewery make $3$ different beers and only know the
> participants preferences which is:
>
> $8$ people prefer lager, $7$ people prefer porter, $5$ people prefer stout.
>
> How many of each beer should they brew to give participants what they want and also minimize waste?

Generally, such problems have intersecting preference values, like the total number of people whose preference information is available will be more than the total number of participants. This would signify that more than one beer is preferred by one person & there is some intersection in the venn diagram. This question lacks such information. It simply has a single beer information. For the second beer, we can only guess. How do I solve this, or is it even a valid problem? Or there is more information needed here?

Answer (score 0):

I would read the question to imply that each person has a second choice beer which differs from their first choice and that they will take one of each beer.  We are then asked the minimum amount of beer we could allocate to make sure we can accommodate everybody's preference.  How much lager might we need?  The eight people who prefer it each want one.  The other twelve might all have lager as their second choice.  Similarly for the other two beers.  We need to brew $20$ of each to be sure we won't run out.  We will then waste $20$ beers because we brew $60$ and distribute $40$.  Another reading would be to allow people to take two of the same beer if they want.  In that case you might need $28$ lagers as all the people who have that as their favorite could take two.  In that case we need to brew $28+27+25=80$ beers and will waste $40$.  Sorry about that, but if we don't want to disappoint anybody that is what it takes.